# How should I refactor this for Sonar

Tags: java, regex, csv, sonarqube

My sonar plugin for my IDE is complaining about this regex

```
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

because "Regular expressions should not overflow the stack".
When I look on sonar, it gives the following blurb, but I'm not sure how to proceed, can you help?

```
The Java regex engine uses recursive method calls to implement backtracking. Therefore when a repetition inside a regular expression contains multiple paths (i.e. the body of the repetition contains an alternation (|), an optional element or another repetition), trying to match the regular expression can cause a stack overflow on large inputs. This does not happen when using a possessive quantifier (such as *+ instead of *) or when using a character class inside a repetition (e.g. [ab]* instead of (a|b)*).

The size of the input required to overflow the stack depends on various factors, including of course the stack size of the JVM. One thing that significantly increases the size of the input that can be processed is if each iteration of the repetition goes through a chain of multiple constant characters because such consecutive characters will be matched by the regex engine without invoking any recursion.

For example, on a JVM with a stack size of 1MB, the regex (?:a|b)* will overflow the stack after matching around 6000 characters (actual numbers may differ between JVM versions and even across multiple runs on the same JVM) whereas (?:abc|def)* can handle around 15000 characters.

Since often times stack growth can't easily be avoided, this rule will only report issues on regular expressions if they can cause a stack overflow on realistically sized inputs. You can adjust the maxStackConsumptionFactor parameter to adjust this.

Noncompliant Code Example
Pattern.compile("(a|b)*"); // Noncompliant
Pattern.compile("(.|\n)*"); // Noncompliant
Pattern.compile("(ab?)*"); // Noncompliant
Compliant Solution
Pattern.compile("[ab]*"); // Character classes don't cause recursion the way that '|' does
Pattern.compile("(?s).*"); // Enabling the (?s) flag makes '.' match line breaks, so '|\n' isn't necessary
Pattern.compile("(ab?)*+"); // Possessive quantifiers don't cause recursion because they disable backtracking
```

From what I can gather, this regex is used to convert a group of csv lines into various String[]s.

```
//in a loop...
String[] columns = pattern.split(line, -1);
```

Comment: Some background would be helpful here, such as what is your regex supposed to be doing?

Comment: You need to prevent the engine from backtracking where possible - this can be done using possessive quantifiers and/or atomic groups. More than that it’s difficult to say without details of what you’re trying to match…

Comment: quite right @TimBiegeleisen, I'll update the question with that info.

Comment: Try to always avoid using `",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"`. This is a very inefficient pattern and will lead to performance issues with longer strings (there have been question about this on SO). So, use the proper CSV parser. Do not use a single regex "to rule them all".

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it myself, despite encouragement, in the comments, to look elsewhere for a 3rd party library that handles CSV, which I may ultimately do.
Anyway in case anyone else is interested, this worked for me:

```
,(?=([^\"]*+\"[^\"]*\")*+[^\"]*$)
```